# C# protected method accessed by derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Can a derived class access it's base class's protected method with `base.method()`?

Like the following:

```
Class A
{   
  Protected doThis()   
}

Class B : A   
{   
  base.doThis();   
}
```

Comment: @Ernest, it still wont compile. The answer to your question is **yes**, but call should be inside other method, constructor or field initializer

Comment: not that that's valid code

Comment: My bad. Forgot I have to include a method in class B.

Comment: If not homework, it must have been an interview question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just do   `doThis()` in a method in the class

assuming you mean this :-

```
class A
{
    protected void doThis()
    {

    }
}

class B : A
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
         doThis();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the definition of access modifier "protected":

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx